# Solving trigonometry identities by simplifying terms

Tags: trigonometry

Verify the identity by simplifying the left side.

$\sin^2x-\sin^2y=\cos^2y-\cos^2x$

Comment: p.s. [trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) this is the way but I wouldn't call it "simplifying".

Comment: Sum $(\sin (y))^2+(\cos(x))^2$to both sides of the equality.

Comment: Please, add some of your thoughts about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\displaystyle \sin^2x+\cos^2x=\sin^2y+\cos^2y$$ as both are equal to $1$

Now change the sides of $\displaystyle \sin^2y,\cos^2x$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510011/how-to-prove-cot-2x-sec-2x-tan-2x-csc-2x/510028#510028

Answer (score 1):

This can be verified by using $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(y)=1-\sin^2(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2 x-\sin^2 y=1-\sin^2 y-(1-\sin^2 x)=\sin^2 x-\sin^2 y,$$
because
$$\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x,$$
and
$$\cos^2 y=1-\sin^2 y$$